# How to include a param in browsers url when using params instead of url in angular ui routing?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using angular ui routing to route my modules. I know if i add something like 
"url: '/:campKey'," in my state then this will come in the browsers url. But instead i am using params as an array of parameters, it is not possible to have both url and params. So how do i show my campkey in the url in the browser.
Thanks

```
.state('_.work.inside.content', {
views: {
  "": {
    controller: 'InsideContentCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/work/inside/content.html'
  }
},
params: ['campKey', 'from', 'to'],
data: {menu: { isHidden: true }},
resolve: {metric: ['$http', '$stateParams','appName', 'dateFilter', function($http,      $stateParams,appName, dateFilter) {
  if($stateParams.campKey) {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET', 
      url: '/-/api/' + appName + '/campaign/' + $stateParams.campKey +'/inside-content', 
      params: {from: dateFilter($stateParams.from, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), to: dateFilter($stateParams.to, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}
    }).
    success(function(resp, status) {
      return resp.results;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
  }
}]}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching some more i found out that instead of using 'params' as above. I can use url and get my 'campkey' in the browsers url. But i would have to remove 'params'. The changes would be as below.

```
.state('_.work.inside.content', {
url: '/:campKey',
views: {
  "": {
    controller: 'InsideContentCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/work/inside/content.html'
  }
},
data: {menu: { isHidden: true }},
resolve: {metric: ['$http', '$stateParams','appName', 'dateFilter', function($http, $stateParams,appName, dateFilter) {
  if($stateParams.campKey) {
    return $http({
    method: 'GET', 
    url: '/-/api/' + appName + '/campaign/' + $stateParams.campKey +'/inside-content', 
    params: {from: dateFilter($stateParams.from, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), to: dateFilter($stateParams.to, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}
}).
success(function(resp, status) {
  return resp.results;
})
.error(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
});
```

}
}]}